# Complex SQL Query - Joining 5 tables with complex conditions

Tags: sql, join, group-by, progress-db

I have the following tables: Reservations, Order-Lines, Order-Header, Product, Customer. Just a little explanation on each of these tables:

- **Reservations** Contains "reservations" for a billing customer/product combination.
- **Order-Lines** Contains line item detail for orders, including the product they ordered and the qty.
- **Order-Header** Contains header info for orders including the date, customer and billing customer
- **Product** Contains product detail information
- **Customer** Contains Customer detail information.

Below are the tables with their associated fields and sample data:

```
Reservation
bill-cust-key  prod-key  qty-reserved  reserve-date
10000          20000     10            05/30/2014
10003          20000     5             06/20/2014
10003          20001     15            06/20/2014
10003          20001     5             06/25/2014
10002          20001     5             06/21/2014
10002          20002     20            06/21/2014

Order-Item
order-num   cust-key    prod-key    qty-ordered
30000       10000       20000       10
30000       10000       20001       5
30001       10001       20001       10
30002       10001       20001       5
30003       10002       20003       20

Order-Header
order-num   cust-key    bill-cust-key   order-date
30000       10000       10000           07/01/2014
30001       10001       10003           07/03/2014
30002       10001       10003           07/15/2014
30003       10002       10002           07/20/2014

Customer
cust-key    cust-name
10000       Customer A
10001       Customer B
10002       Customer C
10003       Customer D

Product
prod-key    prod-name
20000       Prod A
20001       Prod B
20002       Prod C
20003       Prod D
```

I am attempting to write a query that will show me customer/product combinations that exist in both the reservation and order-item tables. A little snafu is that we have a customer and a billing customer. The reservation and order-header tables contain both the customers, but the order-item table only contains the customer. The results should display the billing customer. Additionally, there can be several reservations and order-items for the same customer/product combination, so I would like to show a total sum of the qty-reserved and the qty-ordered.

Below is an example of my desired output:

```
bill-cust-key   cust-name   prod-key    prod-name   qty-ordered qty-reserved
10000           Customer A  20000       Prod A      10          10
10003           Customer D  20001       Prod B      15          20
```

This is the query that I have tried and doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
SELECT customer.cust-key, customer.cust-name, product.prod-key, prod.prod-name,
     SUM(order-item.qty-ordered), SUM(reservation.qty-reserved)
FROM ((reservation INNER JOIN order-item on reservation.prod-key = order-item.product-key)
     INNER JOIN order-header on reservation.bill-cust-key = order-header.bill-cust-key and    
     order-item.order-num = order-header.order-num), customer, product
WHERE customer.cust-key = reservation.bill-cust-key
AND product.prod-key = reservation.prod-key
GROUP BY customer.cust-key, customer.cust-name, product.prod-key, product.prod-name
```

I'm sorry for such a long post! I just wanted to make sure that I had my bases covered!

Comment: From a database normalization standpoint, I am curious as to why the order-header, and order-item tables both have the cust-key column?  Does the cust-key in the order-item table match the cust-key in the order-header table?

Comment: @MDiesel Yes - the cust-key in the order-items matches the cust-key in the order-header. Unfortunately, I did not design the database. (There are many other instances like this)

Comment: I totally understand :)  A lot of times things like that are out of the our hands.  I just thought I would ask in case you were able to change it

Comment: @MDiesel Yes, a very frustrating point that I learn to "deal" with. ;-)

Comment: Is writing some progress code a possibility? If it is then a lot of these SQL contortions could go away.

Comment: @TimKuehn Yes - Writing a Progress ABL Procedure is an option. I am a little stronger when it comes to SQL which is why I usually use it as my starting point..

Comment: In that case I've thrown together a starting point for a progress solution and added it as an answer.

Comment: I also tried some of the sub-query examples in the Progress SQL docs and they didn't work - if you have maintenance on this product then a call to Tech Support would be in order.

Comment: If you're trying to use the Progress editor, this is why your query isn't working: https://progress.my.salesforce.com/kA0a0000000dUXf?popup=true

Answer (score 2):

You want to join your tables like this:

```
from reservation res join order-header oh on res.bill-cust-key = oh.bill-cust-key
join order-item oi on oi.order-num = oh.order-num
and oi.prod-key = res.prod-key
/*   join customer c on c.cust-key = oi.cust-key  old one */
join customer c on c.cust-key = oh.bill-cust-key
join product p on p.prod-key = oi.prod-key
```

Comment: I think there are still two issues: 1.I want to list the billing-customer's name, not the (ordering) customer's name. The way this is set up you are joining the customer table on the cust-key from the order-item, not the bill-cust-key from the order-header. I think this one is an easy fix. I changed the join to join customer c on c.cust-key = oh.bill-cust-key. 2. The qty-reserved is incorrect. For example, prod 20001 shows up on two separate orders for cust 10001 (bill-cust 10003). The qty-reserved is being accounted for twice, displaying as 40.

Comment: OK scratch that, it looks like I fixed issue number 2 by changing SUM(reservation.qty-reserved) to SUM(distinct reservation.qty-reserved)

Comment: OK, I lied. This still isn't working. Not only am I having the issue with the qty-reserved being incorrect when there are more than one order-item for a customer/product combination, but the qty-ordered is incorrect when there is more than one customer/product reservation combination. I tried adding DISTINCT to the beginning of the SELECT statement, but that didn't do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I find that it can be very helpful to separate out your output rows from your aggregate rows by using CROSS APPLY (or OUTER APPLY) or simply an aliased inner query if you don't have access to those.

For example,

```
SELECT 
    customer.cust-key, 
    customer.cust-name, 

    tDetails.prod-key, 
    tDetails.prod-name,
    tDetails.qty-ordered,
    tDetails.qty-reserved

FROM customer

--note that this could be an inner-select table in which you join if not cross-join
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
         product.prod-key, 
        prod.prod-name,
        SUM(order-item.qty-ordered) as qty-ordered, 
        SUM(reservation.qty-reserved) as qty-reserved
    FROM reservation
        INNER JOIN order-item ON reservation.prod-key = order-item.product-key
         INNER JOIN product ON reservation.prod-key = product.prod-key
    WHERE
        reservation.bill-cust-key = customer.cut-key
    GROUP BY product.prod-key, prod.prod-name
) tDetails
```

There are many ways to slice this, but you started out the right way saying "what recordset do I want returned".  I like the above because it helps me visualize what each 'query' is doing.  The inner query marked by the CROSS apply is simply grouping by prod orders and reservations but is filtering by the current customer in the outer top-most query.

Also, I would keep joins out of the 'WHERE' clause.  Use the 'WHERE' clause for non-primary key filtering (e.g. cust-name = 'Bob').  I find it helps to say that one is a table join, the 'WHERE' clause is a property filter.

**TAKE 2 - using inline queries**

This approach still tries to get a list of customers with distinct products, and then uses that data to form the outer query from which you can get aggregates.

```
SELECT 
    customer.cust-key, 
    customer.cust-name, 

    products.prod-key, 
    products.prod-name,

    --aggregate for orders
    (   SELECT SUM(order-item.qty-ordered) 
        FROM order-item 
        WHERE
            order-item.cust-key = customer.cust-key AND
            order-item.prod-key = products.prod-key) AS qty-ordered,

    --aggregate for reservations
    (   SELECT SUM(reservation.qty-reserved)
        FROM reservations
            --join up billingcustomers if they are different from customers here
        WHERE
            reservations.bill-cust-key = customer.cust-key AND
            reservations.prod-key = products.prod-key) AS qty-reserved

FROM customer

    --get a table of distinct products across orders and reservations
    --join products table for name
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT order-item.prod-key FROM order-item
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT reservation.prod-key FROM reservations
    ) tDistinctProducts
        INNER JOIN products ON products.prod-key = tDistinctProducts.prod-key
```

**TAKE 3 - Derived Tables**

According to some quick googling, Progress DB does support derived tables.  This approach has largely been replaced with CROSS APPLY (or OUTER APPLY) because you don't need to do the grouping.  However, if your db only supports this way then so be it.

```
SELECT 
        customer.cust-key, 
        customer.cust-name, 

    products.prod-key, 
    products.prod-name,

   tOrderItems.SumQtyOrdered,

   tReservations.SumQtyReserved

FROM customer

    --get a table of distinct products across orders and reservations
    --join products table for name
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT order-item.prod-key FROM order-item
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT reservation.prod-key FROM reservations
    ) tDistinctProducts
        INNER JOIN products ON products.prod-key = tDistinctProducts.prod-key

    --derived table for order-items
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (   SELECT 
                            order-item.cust-key,
                            order-item.prod-key,
                            SUM(order-item.qty-ordered) AS SumQtyOrdered
                        FROM order-item 
                        GROUP BY 
                            order-item.cust-key,
                            order-item.prod-key) tOrderItems ON
                                    tOrderItems.cust-key = customer.cust-key AND
                                    tOrderItems.prod-key = products.prod-key

    --derived table for reservations
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (   SELECT
                            reservations.bill-cust-key,
                            reservations.prod-key,
                            SUM(reservations.qty-reserved) AS SumQtyReserved
                        FROM reservations
                            --join up billingcustomers if they are different from customers here
                        WHERE
                            reservations.bill-cust-key = customer.cust-key AND
                            reservations.prod-key = products.prod-key) tReservations ON
                                tReservations.bill-cust-key = customer.cust-key AND
                                tReservations.prod-key = products.prod-key
```

Comment: Maybe I am just a n00b, but this isn't working. I'm getting an error that basically says that "customer.cust-key" cannot be found or is not specified for the query. I'm not familiar with CROSS JOINS (or OUTER APPLY's) for that matter. Does customer need to be defined within the CROSS JOIN?

Comment: I don't have your table setup here, but CROSS APPLY is basically like a 'INNER APPLY'.  It just is taking an inner query and 'applying' it to each of the outer rows (your customers).  You can reference the outer rows in the inner query.

All of this can also be done with joining an inner table, but it's more cumbersome.

What database are you using?

Comment: It's a Progress DB. Unfortunately, doesn't seem that it can handle a CROSS APPLY. I tried modifying to use an INNER-SELECT table. I'm now receiving the same issue that I outlined in the other answer. For example, if there are two records in reservation for the same customer/product combination, the qty-ordered (from order-item) is doubled. If there are three records in order-item for the same customer/product combination, the qty-reserved (from reservation) is multiplied by 3. I am able to fix one of the values (EITHER qty-ordered OR qty-reserved) using distinct, but not both.

Comment: I added an example with 'CROSS JOIN' which is a much older command that will likely be supported.  Basically, it's the same as not joining a table (e.g. SELECT * FROM products,reservations = SELECT * FROM products CROSS JOIN reservations).  It produces the outer query of customers/products and then inline aggregates calculate it for you.  There are definitely performance improvements to be had, but it should come close (hopefully).

Comment: I think I have yet more bad news for you. I am receiving an error stating "Error: Syntax error in SQL statement at or about "SELECT SUM(order-item.qty-ordered)". After some digging around, it looks like Progress cannot handle subqueries in the SELECT statement.

Comment: I added a final attempt using derived tables which I believe is supported by Progress DB.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your original code and request, here's the starting point of a Progress solution -

```
DEFINE VARIABLE iQtyOrd         AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iQtyReserved    AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

FOR EACH order-item
    NO-LOCK,

    EACH order-header
        WHERE order-header.order-num = order-item.order-num
        NO-LOCK,

    EACH reservation
        WHERE reservation.prod-key      = order-item.prod-key    AND
              reservation.bill-cust-key = order-header.bill-cust-key
        NO-LOCK,

    EACH product
        WHERE product.prod-key = reservation.prod-key
        NO-LOCK,

    EACH customer
        WHERE customer.cust-key = reservation.bill-cust-key
        NO-LOCK

    BREAK BY customer.cust-key
          BY product.prod-key
          BY product.prod-name
    :

    IF FIRST-OF(customer.cust-key) OR FIRST-OF(product.prod-key) THEN
        ASSIGN
            iQtyOrd = 0
            iQtyReserved = 0
            .

    ASSIGN
        iQtyOrd         = iQtyOrd + reservation.qty-ordered
        iQtyReserved    = iQtyReserved + reservation.qty-reserved
        .

    IF LAST-OF(customer.cust-key) OR LAST-OF(product.prod-key) THEN
        DISPLAY
                customer.cust-key
                customer.cust-name
                product.prod-key
                prod.prod-name
                iQtyOrd
                iQtyReserved
            WITH FRAME f-qty
                DOWN
                .

END.
```